# Client side html/css/js validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Are there any HTML5 feature or some JS script that could validate HTML, CSS and JS code on the client side ?

So I would just need to pass my code to function calls, and It would return me validation results that I could display somewhere in the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 5 feature? No.

JS script?

It is *possible* to write HTML and CSS validators in JavaScript, I don't know anyone who has though. The W3C publish the code for their [markup](http://validator.w3.org/source/) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html) validation services, so you could port it if you were willing to spend the time and effort.

[JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) and [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/) are the popular tools for linting JavaScript in JavaScript.